# Does URL being rewritten in browser closes the socket connection between the browser and the server?

Tags: python, reactjs, http, wsgi, bottle

I'm debugging an application with React front-end and Python back-end talking to each other by HTTP.

Let's say user enter `/find?name=foo`, with `foo` is not a existed value.

I observe two events happen:

- the front-end rewrites the URL to `/find` using `history.pushState`.
- In the back-end, a BrokenPipe exception happens.

I guess two events are related, since (I guess) the back-end is trying to write into a closed socket.

I want to see if my hypothesis is correct or not. So my question is, does browser URL being rewritten closes the previous socket connection?

Thank you.

Comment: are you talking about websockets, or just vanilla HTTP(S)?

Comment: @SamMason just vanilla HTTP

Comment: HTTP responses are designed to be "fast", thus the connection will normally be closed a long time before any user attempts to enter any search term.  maybe you're trying to do something else "special" that is breaking this.  I'd expect submitting a form to abort any in-progress page load.  if you're trying to do something like "long-polling" you might want to use something else